# Remove Tumblr's new "Login Wall"?

Tags: tumblr, greasemonkey

I found today while searching Tumblr that the website is now doing a new annoying thing where after scrolling through results for a moment it removes the scroll bar and demands you sign in to the site, adding "?source=login_wall" in the url bar. It wasn't doing this yesterday. How do I stop Tumblr from putting up this new "Login Wall" or remove it, without being logged in? Perhaps a script for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey to run on Tumblr while searching?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/395497-login-reminder-popup-remover) script on greasyfork for the GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey/ViolentMonkey extensions that I found successfully stops Tumblr from putting up it's "Login Wall", along with several other sites.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Simply and quick JavaScript solution:

```
document.getElementById('glass-container').remove();
```

I've put it in a bookmarklet:

`javascript:(function()%7Bconsole.log(%22Removing%20Tumblr%20Login%20wall!%22)%3Bdocument.getElementById('glass-container').remove()%7D)()`